# Box2D, AndEngine - Can I attach another sprite to a body?

Tags: box2d, andengine

Probably an easy question. I already have a body set up with a sprite. I was just wondering if it would be possible to attach another sprite. If I attach the new sprite to the original sprite, then it doesn't stay consistent with the physics from the body; it kinda just goes crazy! Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :D

edit: attached code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rM.carArray.length; i++) {
        rM.carArray[i] = new Car(new Sprite(
                rM.spawnPoint[i].getSpawnPos().x,
                rM.spawnPoint[i].getSpawnPos().y,
                ResourceManager.getInstance().car_region, // creates a new
                                                            // sprite for
                                                            // car in car
                                                            // array
                engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

Sprite glower = new Sprite(rM.carArray[i].getSprite().getX() + (rM.carArray[i].getSprite().getWidth()/2), rM.carArray[i].getSprite().getY(), rM.carLights_region, vbom);                
        rM.carArray[i].setGlower(glower);
        rM.carArray[i].getSprite().setUserData(rM.carArray[i].getBody());
        rM.carArray[i].setBody(rM.carBodyArray[i] = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rM.carArray[i].getSprite(), BodyType.DynamicBody, carFixtureDef), "car");
        mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(rM.carArray[i].getSprite(), rM.carArray[i].getBody(), true, true));
        rM.carArray[i].getBody().setLinearVelocity(GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentDefaultSpeed(), 0);
}
```

As you can see, I set up my car array (the car constructor takes 1 parameter.. a sprite). Afterwards, I set up it's sprite, connect the first sprite to the body and all of that. In this case, 'glower' is the headlights. I tried attaching them to the cars sprite, but alas my problem :(

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the two sprites to move according to the body movement?

Comment: Essentially, yeah :D Basically, I have a car all set up, but I want to attach headlights to it. Thing is, I want to turn these on and off, so I will set them to visible and invisible when needed. I figured the easiest way would be to add another sprite, but as mentioned previously, I am not sure how to get it to work with the initial body :(

Comment: ok, please, attach relevant code where you attach both sprites

Comment: hi ssantos. added the code to the original post. hope it helps you help me :)

Comment: add your headlights as a child to your car.So that make visible and invisible by calling  car.getChildByTag().setVisible();

Comment: Sorry I am not sure that I understand what you mean. Add it as a child how? attach it to the sprite?